# How can I profile tomcat on mac os X?

Tags: java, tomcat, profiling, eclipse-tptp

I am running an independent (I mean not inside any IDE) tomcat instance. I want to profile my application because it seams to respond really slow in a particular use case.

So, I tried installing TPTP on my mac os x 10.4 (tiger) but it seams that there is no version available.

Then I tried to just set "JAVA_OPTS="-Xmx512m -XrunpiAgent:server=enabled" in tomcat/bin/setenv.sh
but it threw the following error:

Error occurred during initialization of VM Could not find agent library: libpiAgent.jnilib (searched /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.5.0/Libraries:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:.)

I was pretty happy with the TPTP (with eclipse) on windows.

Any ideas?
Regards,
Sandeep Giri

Answer (score 1):

TPTP is not available on Mac yet. I ended up using

```
/Developer/Application/Performance Tools/Shark.app
```

Comment: Does Shark allows debugging tomcat applications?